# Get element by generate in jQuery in Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, selenium, xpath

I have a textbox. It only accept number type into it. When type a string and `sendKeys(Keys.TAB)`, it will show an error message popup. This popup is append by jQuery with `id="message_eff"` and doesn't exist before.

I tried with this code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='messagefor_eff']"));
```

and run my test.
I run my test 10 times, but sometimes it make an error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='messagefor_eff']"}
```

How to fix this error and make this error appear again?

Comment: have you given enough timeout before you try to find the error message?

Comment: Yes. I add `Thread.sleep(2000);` before it. But it's doesn't worked.

Comment: my guess is Javascript is not enabled when the browser is launched by Selenium. Can you try setting javascript enabled to true in desired capabilities for the browser and then try the test again?

Answer (score 0):

Try to incorporate [*explicit wait*](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) before locating dynamically generated elements :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='messagefor_eff']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='messagefor_eff']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to switch to the alert before looking for the element:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='messagefor_eff']"));
```

See: https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/js_alerts_prompts_and_confirmations/